# ALAsset timestamp returns wrong date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, alasset, assetslibrary

I am trying to get the timestamp of images, I can get the correct latitude and longitude values, but the timestamp always returns the current time, not the EXIF time of the image.

```
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultsBlock = ^(ALAsset *asset) {
    CLLocation *imageLoc = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YY HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *trailTime = [formatter stringFromDate:imageLoc.timestamp];
    NSLog(@"---+++ image TimeStamp: %@", trailTime);
    [formatter release];
```

Any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I found the answer
What gave me the entire metadata in dictionary format was:

```
NSDictionary *metadata = asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata;
```

//Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 13):

You will need to get the date using [`ALAssetPropertyDate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/ALAssetPropertyDate) key.

```
NSDate * date = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
/* Use the `NSDateFormatter` instance to print the date */
```

Comment: Thanks, This returns the date/time the image was saved. So if say an image is edited or taken with a photo app then transfered to the camera roll, the date/time will be wrong

Comment: OK I found the answer: the ALAssetPropertyLocation timestamp contains a time only no date, surely an omission. 
What gave me the entire metadata in dictionary format was:

NSDictionary *metadata = asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata;

Hope this helps others.

Comment: @RexMac66 You should post that as an answer and accept it, or accept this answer above if it helped solve the issue.  This way future readers will know what worked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're fetching location to get the date. you should be doing something like the following:

```
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [assetsLib enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                             usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

                                 [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

                                     //If you'd want to directly fetch from it's external property, which seems more appropriate.
                                     NSDate *date = [result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
                                     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                                     [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
                                     [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss ZZZ"];
                                     NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

                                     //If you'd want to fetch the date from metaData
                                     ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [result defaultRepresentation];
                                     NSDictionary *dictionaryOfMetaData = [assetRep metadata];

                                     NSLog(@"dictionary:%@ \n \
                                           date:%@ \n \
                                           StringDate:%@", [[dictionaryOfMetaData valueForKey:@"{TIFF}"] valueForKey:@"DateTime"],
                                           date,
                                           stringDate);
                                 }];
                             }
                           failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                              //Handle Error!  
                           }];
```